# What is the difference between cookies maxAge and expiry

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I'm on NodeJS, Express app i am using cookies for some features of my app. I need to set cookie life to one month.

For this very purpose i've set cookie maxAge to `days*hoursPerDay*minutesPerHour*secondsPerMinute*1000` to achieve one month time `30*24*60*60*1000` = `2592000000`.

Yet in browser expiry of my cookies is near 10 hours.

What am i missing, my calculations are wrong? or I am using wrong attribute(`maxAge`)?

Also what is the difference between `maxAge` and `expiry` attribute of cookies?

Comment: Not a Express user but... Raw cookies require setting a concrete date so `maxAge` is probably a convenience wrapper.

Answer (score 5):

As far as i know, `maxAge` wont save in cookie's specifications.
As [Don't trust Cookie setMaxAge](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073096/don-t-trust-cookie-setmaxage.html) demonstrated, The mechanism of `maxAge` works like ***Change/manipulate expiration date of cookie (based on SERVER_SIDE) but browser checks cookie's expiration date, based on CLIENT_SIDE.***
From my point of view, This is misbehavior. Because in order to make `max-age` work as expected, both client/server DateTime should be synchronized.

Comment: I mean, yes Internet Explorer (IE6, IE7, and IE8) does not support “max-age”, but who cares. It’s no longer 2009 (the date of the cited blog post).

Answer (score 1):

maxAge should be set in milliseconds ( i was wrong, as i referred to client part)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

are you setting coolie like below?

res.cookie('rememberme', '1', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true })
http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie

Comment: but when i used `900000` it gave me 15mintues?

Comment: how are you testing and confirming its only 1 hour, i mean do you change the browser/client time values?

Comment: i am using chrome's developer tools for debugging almost all frontend aspects of my app...

Comment: 900, 000 milliseconds should be 15 minutes.